# Chat message are not receiving after reconnecting internet chat in Quick Blox?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have problem with sending messages after reconnecting with the quickblox server.If I disconnect my internet from device then again reconnect, the chat messages is not sending. But the log shown it was sent , not showing the receive log. The reconnect code works fine but cannot chat anymore.

when it was working as fine,

```
2013-10-12 10:48:37.033 football365[1000:8517] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] ->              Message: <message to="4099_000000001000000003@muc.chat.quickblox.com" id="7" type="groupchat"><body>hello</body></message>
2013-10-12 10:48:37.463 football365[1000:8517] -[QBChat xmppRoom:didReceiveMessage:fromNick:] -> message: <message xmlns="jabber:client" type="groupchat" to="578338-4099@chat.quickblox.com/tigase-11258" from="4099_000000001000000003@muc.chat.quickblox.com/578338"><body>hello</body></message> fromNick: 578338
```

when message only sent, the received log is not shown.

```
2013-10-12 10:48:37.033 football365[1000:8517] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] ->              Message: <message to="4099_000000001000000003@m
```

I am also getting when I am sending message after connecting internet

```
if (QBChatServiceErrorConnectionClosed)
    {
        NSLog(@"connection QBChatServiceErrorConnectionClosed");
    }
    if (QBChatServiceErrorConnectionTimeout)
    {
        NSLog(@"connection QBChatServiceErrorConnectionTimeout");
    }
```

Comment: this is happening whenever I disconnect and reconnect internet in the device

Comment: Please try this version https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2z9ytvckd6zeifs/Quickblox.framework2.0.12.zip as a temporary solution ( for future use please use Cocoa Pods )